# How can I solve the interface error with lightHouse in Laravel?

Tags: graphql

I have a problem, I have contacts but it is divided into Person or company, create an `interface` but at the moment of executing it it generates an error:

```
#contact types
enum contactType{
    persona @enum(value: 2)
    empresa @enum(value: 3)
}
enum contactIdType{
    cedula @enum(value: 1)
    nit @enum(value: 2)
    pasaporte @enum(value: 3)
    cedula extranjera @enum(value: 4)
}
interface Contact{
    id_contact:ID!
    type:contactType!
    name:String!
    identification_type:contactIdType!
    identification_number:Int!
    email:String!
    phones:String!
    state:Int!
    address:String
    web_site:String
}

type Person implements Contact{
    id_contact:ID!
    id_parent_contact:Int
    id_job:Int
    type:contactType!
    name:String!
    lastname:String
    identification_type:contactIdType!
    identification_number:Int!
    email:String!
    phones:String!
    state:Int!
    address:String
    web_site:String
}

type Company implements Contact{
    id_contact:ID!
    type:contactType!
    name:String!
    identification_type:contactIdType!
    identification_number:Int!
    email:String!
    phones:String!
    state:Int!
    locate:String
    city:String
    address:String
    web_site:String
}
```

Query:

```
type Query {    
    #Contacts
    contacts: [Contact!]! @all(model: "App\\Contact")
    contacts_paginator: [Contact]! @paginate(type: "paginator" model: "App\\Contact")
    contact(name: String! @eq): Contact @find(model: "App\\Contact")

}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
query{
  contacts{
    name
    type     
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "debugMessage": "Abstract type Contact must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Query.contacts with value \"{\"id_contact\":4,\"id_parent_contact\":null,\"id_job\":null,\"type\":2,\"name\":\"Laura\",\"lastname\":\"Sanchez\",\"identification_type\":1,\"identification_number\":1049342129,\"email\":\"laura@gmail.com\",\"phones\":\"3203428890\",\"state\":1,\"locate\":null,\"city\":null,\"address\":null,\"web_site\":null}\", received \"Contact\". Either the Contact type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible type should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function.",
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "contacts",
        0
      ]
```

i am working with laravel lighthouse

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. Let me break it down for you:

```
Abstract type Contact must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Query.contacts
```

You are returning an interface `Contact` from your field. GraphQL needs to determine a concrete Object type, in your case `Company` or `Person`.

```
Either the Contact type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible type should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function.
```

That part tells you what needs to happen: You need some way to determine whether an entry of `Contact` is either a `Company` or a `Person`.

Usually, Lighthouse can determine that automatically, if you are using different model classes. It appears you are using the same one, so you have to implement a custom type resolver.

You can simply create one with:

```
php artisan lighthouse:interface Contact
```

Read more about interfaces in Lighthouse: https://lighthouse-php.com/master/the-basics/types.html#interface

Answer (score 0):

Now the error changed, since he believes:
`lighthouse:interface contact`
and that generated this file:

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Interfaces;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\TypeRegistry;

class Contact
{
    /**
     * The type registry.
     *
     * @var \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\TypeRegistry
     */
    protected $typeRegistry;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param  \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\TypeRegistry  $typeRegistry
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(TypeRegistry $typeRegistry)
    {
        $this->typeRegistry = $typeRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Decide which GraphQL type a resolved value has.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $rootValue The value that was resolved by the field. Usually an Eloquent model.
     * @param  \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext  $context
     * @param  \GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo  $resolveInfo
     * @return \GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type
     */
    public function resolveType($rootValue, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo): Type
    {
        // Default to getting a type with the same name as the passed in root value
        // TODO implement your own resolver logic - if the default is fine, just delete this class

        return $this->typeRegistry->get(class_basename($rootValue));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "debugMessage": "Argument 2 passed to App\\GraphQL\\Interfaces\\Contact::resolveType() must be an instance of App\\GraphQL\\Interfaces\\GraphQLContext, instance of Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Context given, called in C:\\Users\\Guecha\\Laravel-projects\\APP_ControlIngenieria\\app\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\InterfaceType.php on line 114",
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "contacts",
        0
      ],
```

In my models I have:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    protected  $table= 'contacts';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_contact';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_parent_contact',
        'id_job',
        'type',
        'name',
        'lastname',
        'identification_type',
        'identification_number',
        'email',
        'phones',
        'state',
        'locate',
        'city',
        'address',
        'web_site'
    ];
}
```

I don't know what the error is :(